# Can't restore a viewPager state from Parcelable

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my CustomPageAdapter class I have implemented those two methods to restore the viewPager state. To test it, for the simplicity I'm trying to pass integer and retreive it however I still got 0. Here is the method implementation:

```
 @Override
 public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader arg1) {
 if (state instanceof Bundle) {
    Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
    saved = bundle.getInt("stateToSave");
    super.restoreState(bundle.getParcelable("instanceState"), arg1);
    return;
 }
 super.restoreState(state, arg1);
 }

 @Override
 public Parcelable saveState() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("instanceState", super.saveState());
    bundle.putInt("stateToSave", 8);
    return bundle;
 }
```